# How to use gsutil to download from google cloud storage to AWS instance or s3 bucket with a http link?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a google cloud storage download http link and I would like to directly download the file to AWS instance or s3 bucket. I've tried gsutil cp or rsync, but they don't support sending credential as parameters.
Here is the link.

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/<FILE PATH>?x-goog-signature=<SIGNATURE>&x-goog-algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&x-goog-credential=<CREDENTIAL>goog4_request&x-goog-date=<DATE>Z&x-goog-expires=<EXPIRES>&x-goog-signedheaders=host
```

Comment: That looks like a signed URL. You shouldn't have to supply any credentials or use gsutil or rsync. Just use curl or wget. For example: `wget -O filename.zip "thesignedurl"`

Comment: @jarmod Thank you. I tried wget before but it didn't work. I guess I didn't use double quote "".

Comment: Hey @LionLai, did you manage to get it working?

Comment: Yes, after adding double quote "" around the URL, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a signed URL in hand, which you appear to, then you don't need to supply any credentials (the signed URL includes everything needed) and you don't need to use gsutil or rsync.

You can use an HTTP client such as curl or wget. For example:

```
wget -O filename.zip "https://the-signed-url-here"
```

Be sure to quote the signed URL, as shown above, because it will have ampersand (`&`) characters in it and these are treated in a special way by many operating systems and shells (typically [start in background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line)).

Answer (score 1):

As *@jarmod* mentioned, you should be able to download an object from the GCS using tools like `wget` or `curl` once you have an accessible URL to it, and then upload it to Amazon S3.

However, GCP provides other [ways](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability) to achieve that as well. For instance, you can interact with Amazon S3 using the [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability#using_the_gsutil_command_line) tool as you intended initially by running `gsutil cp` or `gsutil rsync`. For that, you would need to add your Amazon S3 credentials to the [.boto](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil) configuration file for gsutil.